# The editor preview and the final rendered output do not match spacing for tabs

Tags: support, code-formatting, tabs

In context of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452430/how-are-bitmap-indexes-helpful) that I posted, there is a discrepancy between the preview and the final rendered output.

In the editor

[image]

Final rendered

[image]

Note the difference between the column alignments and spacing.

Comment: Also, [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/) is `status-completed`.

Comment: Here is opened the another topic - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299528/error-in-edit-preview-functionality-when-using-tabs-in-a-code-block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen if you have embedded tabs.

The server converts tabs to spaces behind the scenes, but the javascript preview does not.

So if you want the preview to match, use spaces not tabs.